# How to move a sheet from one Workbook to another using apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I would like to move a sheet ("HeaderSheet") from one workbook ("HeaderSpreadsheet") to another workbook ("ReportSpreadsheet").
Is it possible??

I tried the following without success:

```js
var HeaderSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Url_1')
var ReportSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Url_2')
  
HeaderSheet = HeaderSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Header")  
  
ReportSpreadsheet.insertSheet('Data', 1, {template: HeaderSheet})
```

Alternatively, could I copy the content from the Header workbook to the Report one?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Did you even look in the Apps Script documentation?? Doing research is a required part of asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my question was already solved.

This may be useful:

[Google Apps Script, copy one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791132/google-apps-script-copy-one-spreadsheet-to-another-spreadsheet-with-formatting)