# Copy Spreadsheet to a new file, specify tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am copying a new instance of my spreadsheet without formulas into a folder. I found a script that works great here:
[Copy an entire Spreadsheet, Just Preserve the Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923439/copy-an-entire-spreadsheet-just-preserve-the-values).

I was trying to define a specific tab to copy but no luck.

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('tab to dowload');
```

and

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[2]);
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
  var destFolderId = "###";  // Please set the destination folder ID.

  // Copy each sheet in the source Spreadsheet by removing the formulas as the temporal sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var tempSheets = ss.getSheets().map(function(sheet) {
    var dstSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheet.getSheetName() + "_temp");
    var src = dstSheet.getDataRange();
    src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: true});
    return dstSheet;
  });

  // Copy the source Spreadsheet.
  var destination = ss.copy(ss.getName() + " - " + new Date().toLocaleString());

  // Delete the temporal sheets in the source Spreadsheet.
  tempSheets.forEach(function(sheet) {ss.deleteSheet(sheet)});

  // Delete the original sheets from the copied Spreadsheet and rename the copied sheets.
  destination.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetName.indexOf("_temp") == -1) {
      destination.deleteSheet(sheet);
    } else {
      sheet.setName(sheetName.slice(0, -5));
    }
  });

  // Move file to the destination folder.
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(destination.getId());
  DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId).addFile(file);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
}
```

Comment: Did you try modifying the line var tempSheets = ss.getSheets().map(function(sheet) { ...?
getSheets gets all the sheets on the spreadsheet. There is .getSheetByName. to only pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to pass selected sheets, based on their name, to the newly created file.

You can do that by defining a list with the selected sheets:

`var selected_sheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet5'];`

and then instead of using `ss.getSheets()` which gets every sheet, use this to get the sheet object of the selected sheet names:

```
var tempSheets = selected_sheets.map(sn=>ss.getSheetByName(sn))
    .map(function(sheet) {
    var dstSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheet.getSheetName() + "_temp");
    var src = dstSheet.getDataRange();
    src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: true});
    return dstSheet;
  });
```

### Solution:

Please modify this list: `var selected_sheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet5'];` and replace `Sheet1`, `Sheet5` to the name of your sheets. You can also have one sheet: e.g. `var selected_sheets = ['Sheet1'];`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
  var destFolderId = "###";  // Please set the destination folder ID.

  // Copy each sheet in the source Spreadsheet by removing the formulas as the temporal sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var selected_sheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet5']; // Add the sheets you want to copy here!
  var tempSheets = selected_sheets.map(sn=>ss.getSheetByName(sn))
    .map(function(sheet) {
    var dstSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheet.getSheetName() + "_temp");
    var src = dstSheet.getDataRange();
    src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: true});
    return dstSheet;
  });     

  // Copy the source Spreadsheet.
  var destination = ss.copy(ss.getName() + " - " + new Date().toLocaleString());

  // Delete the temporal sheets in the source Spreadsheet.
  tempSheets.forEach(function(sheet) {ss.deleteSheet(sheet)});

  // Delete the original sheets from the copied Spreadsheet and rename the copied sheets.
  destination.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetName.indexOf("_temp") == -1) {
      destination.deleteSheet(sheet);
    } else {
      sheet.setName(sheetName.slice(0, -5));
    }
  });

  // Move file to the destination folder.
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(destination.getId());
  DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId).addFile(file);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a treat. I really appreciate your help.