# If I insert or delete a row in one google sheet how can automatically insert or delete same row in other google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am working with a very detailed sheet that I have created in Google sheet. I have multiple parameters that I use in other sheets.
My question is this, is there a way to "link" the value from one sheet to other sheets, so that if I added a row to the one sheet, it will automatically add a row to the 'linked' sheet in the exact same position with the same formatting?

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can reference data from another sheets into your sheet. That should serve your usecase if your range is pre defined. Another solution, I can think right of my mind is making an app script that duplicates the sheet. Solution is already available at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791132/google-apps-script-copy-one-spreadsheet-to-another-spreadsheet-with-formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Actually, the range of the row isn't defined so I think reference may not help me.
Will check the link thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at  [`=IMPORTRANGE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)?

I think it may be exactly what you are looking for. Imagine you have a sheet like this:

[image: Referenced sheet]

You could copy this whole range using `IMPORTRANGE`

[image: Target Sheet]

After that all the changes on the first sheet will automatically update to the second one.