# Copy a range from one spreadsheet to other with formatting using Advanced Spreadsheet API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I need to copy paste a range from template sheet file to current working sheet file. I understand from the below code, that is not possible.

Is it possible to achive this using Sheets API advanced service?

I actually need to copy paste cell widths, formatting, mergedcells etc from template file range to current file

I have tried with

```
function copyToMySheetFromTemplateFileRange()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID_OF_TEMPLATE_SPREADSHEET);
  var tsheet = tss.getSheetByName("SHEET_A")
  
  tsheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns())
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet(1);
  newSheet.getRange(2, 1).activate();
  tsheet.getDataRange().copyTo(newSheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

}
```

Comment: You can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19791578/11225291) .

Comment: No, My idea is to copy range with formatting and I do not want to bring the template sheet to current file.

Comment: You want to copy both values and formatting or just formatting?

Comment: also in your code you insert a new sheet. What difference does it make if you bring the template sheet to your file? (given that you copy the full data range).... But even if you don't want to do that, you can copy the template sheet, get the formatting/values and put them in the new sheet with your current code.

Comment: Bring the template and delete it after copying?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script, copy one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791132/google-apps-script-copy-one-spreadsheet-to-another-spreadsheet-with-formatting)