# Update one Google sheet from another Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have 2 Google sheets:

1. Source Sheet
2. Target Sheet

The source sheet needs to update the values in the Target Sheet.

For example if we consider the below data:

| Color | Size | QTY | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Black | Large | 2 | $100.00 |
| Black | Small | 1 | $50.00 |
| Red | Small | 5 | $250.00 |

What I am trying to achieve is writing a google script that will basically "*push*" data from the "*Source Sheet*" to the "*Target Sheet*"

***Critical to Understand:***

"Target Sheet" would contain the exact same fields / structure, so we need to identify the updated rows and only update those with the new updated information from the "*Source Sheet*"). If you think in terms of SQL this would be something like a `UPDATE {fields} WHERE...` type of statement.

**A few questions / comments:**

- When executing the script in the "**Target Sheet**" - will I need to delete the affected rows first and then append them? or,
- Is there a method where you can directly update the values of the affected rows (similar to `SQL UPDATE`?

I would like to utilise the methods contained in Sheets API v4, eg:

- [Batchupdate](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/sheets/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)
- [BatchUpdateByDataFilter](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/sheets/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdateByDataFilter#json)

***Update:***

1. This questions is *not* answered by the below existing discussion on
   Stack Overflow:

[Google Apps Script, copy one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791132/google-apps-script-copy-one-spreadsheet-to-another-spreadsheet-with-formatting)

Reasons: The above question talks about copyng an entire sheet / range from one sheet to another, where as this question is related to ***UPDATING*** Information from one sheet to another

2. I am not suggesting a realtime link between the documents (ie. using importrange, I am actually wanting to write / paste updated data from one sheet to another

Comment: If you only need to "mirror" the values, only for consulting, you can use =IMPORTRANGE ("Sheet1","A:F"), adapting to your range and Sheet name

Comment: Import is a live link, when you change info in source, target will update real time, I am taking about updating by actually writing and pasting values